# Add "My Location" to Google Maps Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a "My Location" button to my Google Maps fragment inside my app. This is my code so far:

```
package com.example.sander.app;
```

public class GoogleMaps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmaps, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng marker = new LatLng(51.9244201, 4.4777325);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 12));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Testing").position(new LatLng(53.92, 4.47)));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Hello Google Maps!").position(marker));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // This is how I had implemented the setMyLocationEnabled method
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

}
```

}

I've already added the permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml, and googleMap.setMyLocationEnable(true); doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to add the button to my Google Maps fragment

Comment: for location button in map googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); should work

Comment: can you please post how you implemented setMyLocationEnable(true)? what kind of permissions did you add to your Manifest?

Comment: I've added that to the code

Comment: just to get sure but did you check that the method on MapReady will be called?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I don't know. I do know that my map is displayed inside my app & that placing markers works!

Comment: ok, then it wil be called and I am sure that you have enabled the GPS on your phone

Comment: @MichaelMeyer yes i do have my gps enabled

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it is not an activity. It's a fragment

Comment: @SanderBakker its working in my fragment. it does not need Activity just put this code in `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

Comment: Yeah I tried but after that I get call error because of android SDK 21 & permission handling

Comment: Can you post your code please? I need to see an example @SachinShelar

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this code and comment if any problem**`
public class GoogleMaps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trip, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_map_trip);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    LatLng marker = new LatLng(51.9244201, 4.4777325);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 12));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Testing").position(new LatLng(53.92, 4.47)));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Hello Google Maps!").position(marker));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // This is how I had implemented the setMyLocationEnabled method


}
```

}`
**For layout use this code**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_maps_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map_trip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Code works, but I can't see the "My Location" button

Comment: you are using exactly my code or you added my code in your code?

Comment: I'm using your code. You can see it at the top of this topic (updated the code)

Comment: For map and enable my location we need following things so please review these.
1. Permissions in manifest file.
2. Gradle dependency in build.gradle file.
3. Google api console setting(enable api and generate key).
4. Api key from server and google-services.json file.
5. Java and layout code that i gave you.